# Need to Embed the Watermark/background image in OBIEE Reports?

Tags: oracle, analytics, business-intelligence, obiee

I need to embed a background image to my OBIEE reports. I know how to do that for dashboards. Is it possible to do the same for reports as well?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using the default functionality of the product. The only approach I can think is to use javascript to force a background image of the report, but I don't see this working for printed copies of the report etc.

If you absolutely need this, maybe BI Publisher would be a better tool to use for the report? BIP is more focussed on presentation requirements like this.